# Disable Cognito email confirmation after sign up

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have a flutter app that uses Cognito for authentication.

Unlike in Firebase the user needs to confirm the email address, so you can't proceed as a logged in user unless you confirmed the email.

```
      dynamic res = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(username: email, password: password);
```

so after the above line calling `Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser()` will throw a `UserNotConfirmedException`.

How do I disable this or work around it to be able to easily test my app, since I am at my early development stage and the confirmation step will make it last ages.

UPDATE: it is not possible to simply turn it off in the Cognito Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You must confirm the user sign-up using Lambda Triggers.

Here is the javascript for the code that you can use:

```
export function handler(event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback): void {

    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
    callback(null, event);

}
```

with that Lambda Function created you configure your UserPool to trigger it when the user sign-up. You can find information about how to do it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html)